# Laravel Column Manually Added Cannot be Updated

Tags: laravel-5

So I have been searching but I couldn't find the correct answer to this.

I have an existing User table and added a birthdate column via SQL. The column value is being retrieved through user->birthdate but I cannot seem to save the values when i assign them. Is there anything I need to update on Laravel side?

I already tried recreating the model through artisan make:model User

I can assign other values and they are being saved except for the newly added column

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->birthdate = $birthdate;  //NOT BEING SAVED
$user->name = $name;   //VALUE IS BEING SAVED
$user->save();
```

Retrieving is no problem

```
$user = User::find($id);
echo $user->birthdate; // Echoes successfully
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: why have you added the column manually and not using migration ? try adding `dd($user)` after `$user->birthdate = $birthdate;` and see if it changes the `birthdate` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In the user model you need to add birthdate to fillable array

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'birthdate', 'password'];
```